# Model missed by both EventSystem.current.RaycastAll and IPointerClickHandler when scaling time

Tags: unity

**Update 3:** I've found a workaround, but why the problem only manifests when scaling time still mystifies me. Bounty still up for grabs if someone can work out why.

**Original post:**

I have a situation where a model is ignored in favour of one behind it. The rear model is returned by `EventSystem.current.RaycastAll`, and the front model's `IPointerClickHandler` callback isn't triggered if the rear model is present. The rear model does not implement `IPointerClickHandler` (or pointer up/down handlers, etc). Both these things work on the front model if the rear model isn't there.

Debugging shows that the Raycast is only returning one result. By comparing behaviour when the rear model is and isn't present, I can verify that the distance value in the RaycastResult is greater when hitting the rear model than when hitting the front model.

I can "fix" the problem by using the Inspector to disable and re-enable the front model.

Here's the problem and the "fix" in action:

[image: Tooltips fixed by disabling and re-enabling an object]

Higher quality version [here](https://i.imgur.com/3mod4B9.mp4).

`EventSystem.current.RaycastAll` is used to power the tooltips, and `IPointerClickHandler` is (unsurprisingly) used to get the cube model to react to clicks.

**Update:** After more investigation, I've made limited progress:

- I've fixed the problem when running the game at normal speed by giving both objects a kinematic Rigidbody.
- However, the problem still occurs when I speed up time. I set `Time.timeScale`, and increase `Time.fixedDeltaTime` by the same scale factor as recommended [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html).
- I can eliminate the problem by not changing `Time.fixedDeltaTime`, however I'm reluctant to do so since this has a big impact on framerates at higher speeds (12x being the highest available).
- If time is paused (i.e. `Time.timeScale == 0`) then the problem never fixes itself - time needs to be moving forward for the raycast to start hitting the cube. Presumably this is because physics calculations are suspended when time isn't progressing.

[image]

Again, higher quality version [here](https://i.imgur.com/WAw87Ns.mp4)

Unity version: 2020.3.11f1

**Update 2:** As requested, here's the raycast and time scaling code:

```
public class TooltipDisplay : MonoBehaviour {
    public void FixedUpdate() { // I've tried it in Update too, no change
        PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        pointerData.pointerId = -1;
        pointerData.position = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();
        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerData, results);
        Tooltip highest = null;
        foreach (var result in results) {
            // There's only one result here, and it's often the wrong one :(
            Tooltip t = GetTooltip(result.gameObject);
            if (t == null) continue;
            if (highest == null || t.priority > highest.priority) {
                highest = t;
            }
        }
        // If we found a tooltip, display it.
        // ...
        // ...
    }
}


public class SpeedLimiter {
    
    private int multiplier;
    private static readonly float DEFAULT_FIXED_DELTA_TIME = Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    public const float SECONDS_PER_COMMAND = 2.0f;
    public float timeAccumulated { get; private set; }
    
    // Called from a Unity Button press (bottom-right of video) or from an Input system keypress handler.
    public void SetMultiplier(int speed) {
        multiplier = speed;
        Time.timeScale = multiplier;
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = DEFAULT_FIXED_DELTA_TIME * multiplier;
    }

    public bool Advance() { // Called in Update
        bool looped = false;
        timeAccumulated += Time.deltaTime;
        while (timeAccumulated >= SECONDS_PER_COMMAND) {
           timeAccumulated -= SECONDS_PER_COMMAND;
           looped = true;
        }
        return looped;
    }
}


public class UHexahedron : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3 fromPosition;
    Vector2 toPosition;
    float translationStart;
    float translationDuration;
    bool translating;

    public void FixedUpdate() {
        if (translating) {
            float currentTime = SpeedLimited.timeAccumulated;
            if (currentTime < translationStart) return;
            if (currentTime >= translationStart + translationDuration) {
                Translate(1);
            }
            else {
                float lerp = (currentTime - translationStart) / translationDuration;
                Translate(lerp);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void Translate(float lerp) {
        if (lerp >= 1) {
            transform.position = toPosition; // Tried rigidbody.position, no change
            translating = false;
            return;
        }
        transform.position = Vector3.lerp(fromPosition, toPosition, lerp); // Again, tried rigidbody.position, no change.
    }
}
```

**Update 3:**

It looks like part of the problem was that the `PhysicsRaycaster` on the main `Camera` had its `maxRayIntersections` set to 1. By increasing this I've managed to get the tooltips and click handling working, but it's still unclear why this problem was only occurring when scaling `fixedDeltaTime`.

I started out by implementing a manual physics raycast alongside the `EventSystem` one in order to check that the raycasts were pointing at the correct things. I modified the `TooltipDisplay` code to look like this:

```
public class TooltipDisplay : MonoBehaviour {
    public void FixedUpdate() { // I've tried it in Update too, no change
        PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        pointerData.pointerId = -1;
        pointerData.position = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();
        
        // EventSystem raycast
        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerData, results);
        Tooltip highest = null;
        foreach (var result in results) {
            // There's only one result here, and it's often the wrong one :(
            Tooltip t = GetTooltip(result.gameObject);
            if (t == null) continue;
            if (highest == null || t.priority > highest.priority) {
                highest = t;
            }
        }
        
        // Manual Physics raycast
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(pointerData.position);
        RaycastHit[] physicsResults = Physics.RaycastAll(ray, 100);
        Tooltip manual = null;
        foreach (var rh in physicsResults) {
            Tooltip t = GetTooltip(rh.transform.gameObject);
            if (t == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (manual == null || t.priority > manual.priority) {
                manual = t;
            }
        }
        
        if (highest != null && manual != null) {
            highest = new Tooltip(
                highest.title + " / " + manual.title,
                highest.body,
                highest.priority
        }
        
        // If we found a tooltip, display it.
        // ...
        // ...
    }
}
```

This produced the following behaviour on-screen, where the right-hand half of the tooltip title was always correct, and the left-hand one lagged behind:

[image: EventSystem raycast lagging behind Physics raycast]

This led me to wonder whether the `EventSystem` raycast might be using the wrong camera. This wasn't the problem, but searching around that brought me to [this article](https://gametorrahod.com/eventsystem-raycast-debugging-guide/) which mentioned the limit on the `PhysicsRaycaster` and led me to the fix. I've increased `maxRayIntersections` and everything is now fine.

What remains unclear is why this problem only shows up when changing `fixedDeltaTime`.

**So, although I now have a workaround, if anyone can work out why the original problem only showed up when scaling time, I'll gladly award you the bounty.**

Comment: How are you moving these objects? With transform.position? That leaves their physics representation behind until the next physics step has a chance to match back up, which happens less often with respect to game time when you increase fixedDeltaTime. So the body might not be there yet when the pointer move is handled. Have you tried moving these objects with their rigidbodies, or using SyncTransforms to ensure the latest transform positions are pushed to the colliders in time to process the pointer movements accurately? Also, can you show your RaycastAll code and when you call it?

Comment: I've tried SyncTransforms, that didn't help. I could try moving the rigidbodies instead.

The thing that's confusing me is that the scaling of fixedDeltaTime is to get the physics interval back to 20ms of real time, but the tooltips take much longer than that to update.

Comment: We need to see a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. Not just these 7 lines, but also where they are called, and where you alter your time scale, since all of these pieces appear to be related to the problem.

Comment: I've added the code that handles changing time scaling and cube movement (with comments showing other things I've tried). I tried switching to Rigidbody.position, that didn't help, sadly.

Comment: I would endeavour to visualize the (scaled) raycast using `Debug.DrawLine()`, shown in the scene view. This may give deeper insight into what is happening with the intersection. I would also try a different model than the one that is being missed, to see whether that works, thus implying some problem with your existing model (at least at this timescale), for example, its thickness.

Comment: The smaller collider of the two is a 1m^3 box collider, so it's not exactly tiny. I've updated the question with my latest findings - I've found a workaround, though why the time scaling affects the output is still rather mysterious.